# Inheritance confusion comming from all code behind C# XNA

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

Answered thank you @Corak

I will keep this short as i tend to waffle on and go off topic.
I am trying to exit my XNA game from another class my menu class in my game engine and no matter what i try it simply will not exit.
I thought it was the screen manager i was using but after creating a new project it turns out to be me.

As i understood it the Game1.cs inherits from the XNA Game Class and gets the exit function from that(if i hover the mouse over the exit function in a blank project it says Game.Exit).

So for me to access the same call i would make my class part of the game class like so.

```
public class MainMenu : Game
```

I tried Game1 as-well in my game engine but still the same result it gets called but does not exit but this causes a stack overflow in a blank project for some reason.
Then to access the exit function i just called

```
Exit();
```

The same as it does in the Game1.cs but it simply does not exit, so what is the fundamental thing i am failing to see here ?

In my eyes if the method/function is available for me to see and call why does it not do it ?
The compiler and intellisense is very good at giving you errors so if i need to alter the class in anyway as something not inherited properly why does it not say so.
If i can see everything then surely i can use it ?

Please put me out of my misery.

Regards

Del

Edit:

I seem to be not very good at explaining what i want so here is full code to see what i am trying to do, Everything in the update method of menu i can get to run fine in the game1 update but i need to do it from the menu class.

My Game1.cs

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
// Create my menu
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
SpriteFont MenuFont;

public Game1()
{
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}

protected override void Initialize()
{
base.Initialize();
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
MenuFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Quartz MS");
}

protected override void UnloadContent() { }

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
// Allows the game to exit
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
this.Exit();
// Update Menu
mainMenu.Update(gameTime);
base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
spriteBatch.Begin();

mainMenu.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch, 800, 500, MenuFont);
spriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);
}

}
```

My Menu.cs

```
public class MainMenu : Game
{
// List to store menu items in
private List<string> MenuItems;
// Set some values so we can slow down our menu screen input
float keyPressCheckDelay = 0.30f;
float totalElapsedTime = 0.0f;

private KeyboardState keyboardState;

private int option;
public int Option
{
get { return option; }
set { option = value;
    if (option > MenuItems.Count - 1) option = MenuItems.Count - 1;
    if (option < 0) option = 0;
    }
}

public MainMenu()
{
MenuItems = new List<string>();
MenuItems.Add("Enter Game");
MenuItems.Add("Quit");
Option = 0;
}

public int GetNumberOfOptions()
{
 return MenuItems.Count;
}

public string GetItem(int index)
{
return MenuItems[index];
}

public new void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{           
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
totalElapsedTime += elapsed;

// Update our Keyboard and gamepad states
keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (totalElapsedTime >= keyPressCheckDelay)
{
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{
Option++;
totalElapsedTime = 0.0f;
}

else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) )
{
Option--;
totalElapsedTime = 0.0f;
}

else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
{
if (Option == 0)
{

totalElapsedTime = 0.0f;
Option = 0;
}

if (Option == 1)
{
// how to exit game here ?

Exit();
totalElapsedTime = 0.0f;
Option = 0;
}
}
}

}

public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int screenWidth, int screenHeight, SpriteFont menuFont)
{
int yPos = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < GetNumberOfOptions(); i++)
{
Color colour = Color.White;
if (i == Option)
{
colour = Color.Goldenrod;
}
spriteBatch.DrawString(menuFont, GetItem(i), new Vector2(screenWidth / 2 - menuFont.MeasureString(GetItem(i)).X / 2, yPos), colour);
yPos += 25;
}
}

}
```

Comment: `MainMenu : Game` doesn't mean `MainMenu` is "a part" of `Game`. In the same way `Dog : Animal` doesn't mean `Dog` is "a part" of `Animal`. If you want to access an *instance* of the `MainMenu` class inside an *instance* of the `Game` class, then you need to give that instance of the `Game` class a reference to the instance of the `MainMenu` class.

Comment: You should derive from `Game`. I think you should take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203874.aspx) and alter appropriately. Although I would say the inheritance should be confusing given that you are "saying" a `Menu` is a `Game`; *is it*?; or does it *have* a `Menu`?

Comment: not sure what your trying to say Corak i can access my main menu class fine from the game class thats not my issue.
I can draw my menu scroll up and down, all it does is overlay text over the current screen i can change game state all sorts.

let me alter my 1st post add the full code

Comment: @derekjones - I think you're confusing `class` and `instance of class`. Let's call the instances `gameObject` and `menuObject`. `gameObject` is probably the main object that "runs everything" so when you're calling `gameObject.Exit()`, the program will terminate. Now you have a *separate* `menuObject` that just also happens to have a `Exit()` method (because you let it's class inherit from the `Game` class). Now, when you call `menuObject.Exit()`, the `gameObject` doesn't care at all, because it's a completely different instance.

Comment: So you probably need a way to have `menuObject` call `gameObject.Exit()`. That means `menuObject` somehow needs to get a reference to `gameObject`. Like in a property or as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: If your `Game` class is static, or at least the `Exit()` method is static, then all that becomes moot and you can just call `Game.Exit()` (note the *class* `Game` and not the *instance* `gameObject`) from inside your menu. - But I see that isn't the case here. - In any case, as @BobbyDigital mentioned, saying `Menu` *is a* `Game` (which you do by `Menu : Game`) is probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Corak that clears a lot up, BobbyDigital's sample shows me nothing i don't already know.
Time to give up i think and call it a day.

Comment: So, remove the `: Game` after `public class MainMenu`. Let `MainMenu` have a `private Game game;` field (like the keyboardstate). Change the constructor to `public MainMenu(Game game)` and set `this.game = game` inside the constructor (you'll have to change the instantiation inside `Game1` to `MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu(this);` now).  Now, when you want to exit, call `game.Exit();`. And if that works, try making yourself more familiar with [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173149.aspx). ^_^

Comment: @Corak thank you so much for that makes think much clearer.
Inheritance has always killed me and will continue to be the bain in my life.You would think if i could nail per pixel collision in 20 mins i could get this, to me i can not see the difference if game1 uses game functions whats the difference all your doing is effectively the same thing telling menu to use game like i did in the first place.
Totally illogical captain as spock would say (i know its me i just cant grasp the logic).